# Find the correct fitness function for optimization using Differential Evolution for budgeting problem

Tags: function, optimization, mathematical-optimization, fitness, differential-evolution

i am building a website for recommendation system using differential evolution.
The website will ask the user's budget and some criteria and will return the optimal package. 
The data field look like this and i have 8 dimensions (tables).

```
Id | Name | Price
1  | A    | $100
2  | B    | $300
```

So far i have come up with this equation:

```
f = 1/abs(budget-x1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7-x8)+1
abs=(absolute)
x1 = 1st Dimension $ price
x2 = 2nd Dimension $ price
and so on
```

The +1 at the end is to not be divided by zero, so f=1 would be the best cost/score.

I've tried this formula and if it can't find f=1 then the cost would give bad result.

Someone have a better solution or any literature close to this type of problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So, DE is a great evolutionary algorithm.  DE is fairly simple, on the one hand, while also being reasonably powerful.

However, this problem is a classic integer linear programming problem -- the objective is linear in the variables, and there are no constraints.  Integer linear programming is going to go *so* much faster than any evolutionary algorithm.  I'd look at `pyomo` or `glpk` for open source ILP solvers.

Comment: yeah, i figured DE is too powerful for this type of problem but somehow i need to make it work so that formula is the best i can do. Thanks for the suggestions!